# How to save single document to Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to put into my ES index mapping an exemplary two fielded `book` class entity like below. As a result I ONLY get the index and mapping created but the JSON is not put in the place.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ElasticSearchTransactionsApplicationTests {


    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;



    @Test
    public void shouldCreateSingleBookEntityWitRepository(){
        elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(Book.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(Book.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(Book.class);
        elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Book.class);
        //given

       IndexQuery queryCreatingBookEntity = new BookBuilder("1").setTitle("BBB").buildBookIndex();


        //when
        elasticsearchTemplate.index(queryCreatingBookEntity);
    elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Book.class);

        //then
        assertThat(bookRepository.findOne("1"), is(notNullValue()));
    }
```

**While it creates the index and mapping BUT it does not put the Book inside it - why?**

**EDIT**
Test fils like this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is not null
     but: was null
Expected :is not null

Actual   :null
 <Click to see difference>


    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
```

When I **GET _all/_mapping**

```
{
   "bookshop": {
      "mappings": {
         "book": {
            "properties": {
               "bid": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "title": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Also I check  my index and mapping created but when I try to get the content:
**GET /bookshop/book/1**

```
{
   "_index": "bookshop",
   "_type": "book",
   "_id": "1",
   "found": false
}
```

So I get **found false**. So no book added.

**EDIT 2**
I have ES 2.3.5 form their official repo. below are the version packages.
**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RC1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!--version 2.0.2 to getClient form ElasticTemplate-->
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <!-- For executable JAR packaging-->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository><!--version 2.0.2 to getClient form ElasticTemplate-->
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

**Book.java**

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "bookshop", type = "book", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "-1")
public class Book {

    @Id
    private String bID;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)
    private String title;

}
```

I have also put my book.java with lombok generated @Data and extended @Document content

Comment: You mean this test is failing?

Comment: I have edited the post and put this info. I got the NULL instead of NOT NULL but when I reach for the ElasticSearch it actually also says there is no content of the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My code is almost similar to yours.  I've used this when I was playing with Spring Data Elasticsearch ages ago. I've just updated the version to `1.4.0.RELEASE` The test is passing.

The pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>data-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>data-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Data ES and JPA</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The Book.class

```
package com.demo.model;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

/**
 * Holds the details of book.
 */
@Document(indexName = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    private String bookId;

    private String title;

    public String getBookId() {
        return bookId;
    }

    public void setBookId(String bookId) {
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

The Repository

```
package com.demo.search.repository;

import com.demo.model.Book;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

/**
 * Holds the Elasticsearch CRUD operations for {@link Book} entity.
 */
public interface BookSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, String> {
}
```

And finally, the test.

```
package com.demo.search.repository;

import com.demo.model.Book;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.notNullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

    /**
     * Test things on {@link BookSearchRepository}
     */
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest
    public class BookSearchRepositoryTest {

        @Autowired
        private BookSearchRepository bookRepository;

        @Autowired
        private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

        @Before
        public void before() {

            elasticsearchTemplate.deleteIndex(Book.class);
            elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(Book.class);
            elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(Book.class);
            elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(Book.class);
        }

        @Test
        public void shouldSaveBook(){

            Book book = new Book();
            book.setBookId("1");
            book.setTitle("Learning Scala");

            Book indexedBook = bookRepository.save(book);

            assertThat(indexedBook, is(notNullValue()));
            assertThat(indexedBook.getBookId(), is(book.getBookId()));
            assertThat(bookRepository.findOne("1"), is(notNullValue()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I work on ES 2.3.5 so I had to move to newer versions of the libs in pom. I have edited the primary post to supply my pom.xml ready to use. 
 Can you check if it works with the new version of the libs in pom or mayby the newest 2.3.5 version of ES?

Comment: Yep, your dependencies should work.  `spring-data-elasticsearch-2.0.2.RELEASE` is utilising `elasticsearch-2.3.5`.  See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch/2.0.2.RELEASE.  I've updated my `pom.xml` and my test is still passing.

Comment: I have found the problem. It was the `@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true)` annotation on `title` field in my `Book.java`. I thought it is required to put it on every field.
PS What is this `Modifiable` on Book? I do not have it and it still work?

Comment: No, it isn't required.  Even without the `@Field` annotation the fields will be included in the document when it is indexed.  The only required for the entity to become a valid ES document is the `@Document` and `@Id` from what i remember.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was a super class for my entities.  It has nothing to do with ES document.  Modified my post.

Comment: I wonder why when I put it it breaks it then. 
PS What is this Modifiable extended by Book? I do not have it and it still work?

Comment: Use `@Field` whenever you want to store the field with specific type or format. e.g. Date.  The `title` field of your `book` document should work with or without `@Field` annotation.

Comment: Wired. You are right, now when i put it back it began to work. Then I do not know what caoused the problem. Mayby the lack of `@NoArgsConstructor` form lombok in  Book.java. Hard to say.
 Anyway thank you. I have accepted and upvoted your code answer.